# HTML form submit and redirect combined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a website where the user fills out a form and submits it with a button that sends a POST. I would like the user to submit the POST and be redirected in the same action. Currently I have a javascript redirect (with `window.location`) implemented but I wish the page was condensed better. Is there an easy way for the same element to send a POST and subsequently send a GET to a different address? If it wasn't obvious I'm new to web development so apologies if my terminology is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `action` attribute of the form to the URL you want to process the form.

You can't have a "submit to one URL and redirect to another" in one action.

Your options are:

- Redirect to the second URL from the first one
- Use AJAX to post the the first URL and in JavaScript redirect to the second

Comment: So currently I have <action="url_1" method="post">, how do I change it to essentially include <a href="url_2">?

Comment: @Chris - You can't. Use `action="url_2"`. This will submit to `url_2`.

Comment: Sorry if there was a miscommunication, but I am not trying to submit to url_2. I'm trying to submit to url_1 and navigate to url_2 in the same action.

Comment: @Chris - Not possible. You will need, in `url_1` to have some way to navigate to `url_2`.

Comment: @Chris - An alternative is to use AJAX to post and then redirect.